# I have written a Python progam, but it doesn't do anything when executed

Tags: python

When I run the below code out of CMD, it doesn't do anything, it doesn't also throw any errors. My other Python programs run fine. Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class TinderBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://tinder.com')
        sleep(2)

        fb_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/span/div[2]/button')
        fb_btn.click()

        # switch to login popup
        base_window = self.driver.window_handles[0]
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])

        # vlozit email
        email_in = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
        email_in.send_keys('email')

        # vlozit heslo
        password_in = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
        password_in.send_keys('password')

        # submitnout
        prihlasit_se = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginbutton"]')
        prihlasit_se.click()
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: You never call any of the functions that you define.

Comment: "it doesn't do anything" what are you expecting it to do? You defined a class and never instantiated it or called any of its methods

Comment: In the file above you have only defined a class; you need to create an instance of that class and run it's methods (such as `login`).

Comment: To be honest, there is no need at all for a class here... You can just make `login` a regular function

Comment: And what ever your __TinderBot__ is doing, there is proper API which probably do it better than parsing website.

Comment: add bot = TinderBot() bot.login() in your python file and execute from cmd "python yourfile.py" it will open chrome browser for you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are not calling anything in the code that will give some output, that's why it is not executing.

To get whatever you have to working, you should make an object of the class and then call its functions. Something like this:

```
bot = TinderBot()
bot.login()
```

Answer (score 0):

It technically does a few things, i.e import modules and define a class and its methods. Now you created the tools you'll need in your program, but nothing else, and then your program terminates.

You'll need to actually use them if you want anything meaningful to happen :)

As others suggested: creating an instance of your TinderBot class and calling `.login()` on it is probably what's missing for your code to do what you expect it to.